# Autohotkey variable as hotstring

Tags: autohotkey

I simply just need this to work:

```
:?*C1:%variable%::hello!
```

The `%variable%` is a variable from a database.

I read about a regex library but I couldn't find any examples with this in it, so I am not sure it serves the purpose I need.

The idea behind this is that I am able to change the shortcut for that specific hotstring. Is this possible in any way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

2 options. Either you try creating a script dynamically or you try to match it with regex.

### Dynamic Hotstrings

Get the library here: http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?t=3329

A nice example was also provided:

```
#Include Hotstring.ahk
 
Hotstring("i)((d|w)on)(t)", "$1'$3",3) 
;DONT -> DON'T
;dont -> don't
;dOnt -> dOn't
;WONT -> WON'T
;and so on.
 
Hotstring("i)colou?rs","$0 $0 everywhere!", 3) ; Regex, Case insensitive
; colors -> 'colors colors everywhere!'
; colours -> 'colours colours everywhere!'
```

Comment: Aight I'm just gonna try this then :) I'll be back with some results

Comment: I can't even get this simple example to work `Hotstring("btw", "by the way")`. I have included the file and it's located in the correct folder. Nothing happens when I write btw though? .. hmm @Joe DF

Comment: Do you have the latest version of autohoykey? Try adding `#warn` at the top of your script

Comment: o wow I don't think I have the latest no, because I had some problems with the latest version of ahk together with connection to my mySQL server. That might be a problem.. You mentioned another option though?

Comment: I just downloaded the newest version ANSI 32 and it still doesn't work with Hotstring.ahk.

Comment: okay I got it working finally lol. Uhm though I still don't understand how I would use this for my case? hmm

Comment: Right, what are possible values for variable

Comment: a value could be a string, so ´:?*C1:%variable%::hello!´ %variable% could be "he" (without the ")

Comment: You just have to make a hotstring for every single one :/ ... Regex is closest thing to a variable hot string in ahk

Comment: but as mentioned above, the variable is coming from a database and might be updated after people have the script on their computers. Is this not possible now?

Comment: Make a loop to create a script